# Setting width dynamically for two divs with same id

Tags: html, dynamic, width

I have two or three div elements with same id. Here am setting width dynamically using the following javascript:

function SetWidthRPanelAssessments() {

```
for (var i = 0; i < $("div:visible[id*='s1']").length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById("s1").offsetWidth < 250) {
        var w = document.getElementById("s1");
        w.style.width = 250;
    }
}
```

}

The problem is, it is setting width only for first div and rest of the divs its not setting the value 250. I verified using the alert() but its showing value 250 for all the divs. But not rendering in the screen. How to fix this issue?

This issue is coming in all the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple elements should not have the same ID.  Because of this, the `getElementByID` function only returns the first one with that ID.  Change the IDs to *classes* instead, then use the `getElementsByClassName` function to select them all and iterate through them.

```
function SetWidthRPanelAssessments()
{
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("s1");
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    {
        if (divs[i].offsetWidth < 250) divs[i].style.width = 250;
    }
}
```

Or using jQuery to avoid browser conflicts with `getElementsByClassName`:

```
function SetWidthRPanelAssessments()
{
    $(".s1").each(function(){
        if ($(this).offsetWidth < 250) $(this).css("width","250");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But getElementsByClassName is not supported by IE7 and IE8 browsers. For me the above code needs to be work on IE7 and IE8 too.

Comment: @Iraiyavan try using the [improved getElementsByClassName](http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/) - it should work on older IE browsers as well.

Comment: @Iraiyavan alternatively, you could use jQuery selectors which should handle the browser compatibility for you.  I'll edit the post with a function that uses jQuery as well.